# Django admin: How to show calculated value from entered values dynamically in Django admin form page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have a form which is having a 'price', 'tax' and 'discount' fields (IntegerFields). 
And then one more read-only field will be there called 'total_price'.

while we enter the 'price', 'discount' and 'tax', automatically 'total_price' value should display. If we change the 'discount' or 'price' then 'total_price' also change immediately.

After seeing the final price, we can click the 'Save' button.

How to attain this in Django admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you will have to add custom Javascript code to your admin page.

Here's what you can do:

1. Add read-only field to admin - it will display "total_price"
2. Add custom script to admin page.
3. Write JS script - this script will do "live update" of total price

Your admin may look like this:

```py
@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # some code here...

    readonly_fields = ('total_price', )

    def total_price(self, obj):
        # return whatever initial value you want
        return obj.price - obj.price*obj.discount

    # This is important - adding custom script to admin page
    @property
    def media(self):
        media = super().media
        media._js.append('js/your-custom-script.js')
        return media
```

Remember that `js/your-custom-script.js` must be in your static files folder.

**UPDATE:** 
Instead of overwriting `media` property, you can include your JS using `Meta` nested class:

```py
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    class Media:
        js = (
            'path-to-your-static-script-file.js',
        )
```

The last step is to write a script to update value of `total_price` field whenever some other field is changed.

Example: if you want to change `total_price` whenever `price` is changed, your script can look like this:

```js
if (!$) {
    $ = django.jQuery;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Add event listener to "price" input
    $("#id_price").change(function(e){
        // Get entered value
        let price = parseFloat($(this).val());

        // Get discount value from another field 
        let discount = parseFloat($("#id_discount").val())

        // Compute total price in whatever way you want
        let total_price = price - price*discount;

        // Set value in read-only "total_price" field.
        $("div.field-total_price").find("div.readonly").text(total_price);
    });
})
```

If you want to update `total_price` when `discount` or `tax` fields are changed, simply add event listeners to them.